# Query accounts pending for exactly 2 days - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, filtering

I am trying to query for accounts that have been pending approval for exactly two (2) days. The "created_at" column is timestamp without time zone. The issue I'm facing is I do not know how to filter the "created_at" column to be exactly two days ago. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM kyc_document_check
WHRE status = 'pending'
AND created_at =
```

And I don't know what to put after `created_at =` to make it exactly two days ago.

I'm using PostgreSQL database with pgAdmin-4

Comment: It will depend on your "created_at" date format but try looking up subtracting days from dates. It is possible you'll need to do something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If created_at is a `date`, then use:

```
where created_at = current_date - 2;
```

If it is a `timestamp` it's better to use a range condition because of the time part:

```
where created_at >= current_date - 2
  and created_at < current_date - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM kyc_document_check
WHERE status = 'pending' AND = age(created_at, current_timestamp()) = '2 days'
```